# Error moving uploaded file in Slim framework

Tags: php, file-upload, slim-3

I am trying to upload files using the slim framework but I keep getting this annoying error - `"Error moving uploaded file dumped.jpg to /var/www/html/user-name/src/uploads"

Here is my code:

```
$app->post('/issues/create', function( Request $request, Response $response, array $args ) {
    $files = $request->getUploadedFiles();
    $file  = $files['photo'];

    $destinationPath = __DIR__.'/uploads';

    if( $file->getError() === UPLOAD_ERR_OK ) {
         $file->moveTo($destinationPath);
    }
});
```

Please what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The code itself looks correct, but the error message is not optimal, as it does not specify *what* went wrong when it tried to move the file. I would assume that it is an ownership/permissions issue, those are the most common cause of such errors.

Can you check whether the user who runs your application (probably `www-data`) is allowed to create new files inside of `/var/www/html/safeMonkeyApi/src/uploads`?

Unrelated to the error, you should probably check whether `$files['photo']` is set before you use it. Never trust user input. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Specify the *name* of the new **file** just like this:

```
$uploadPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/uploads/';
$uploadedFiles = $request->getUploadedFiles();
$file = $uploadedFiles['file'];
$file->moveTo($uploadPath . $file->getClientFilename());
```